# Phonegap/Cordova SQLite plugin for windows 7 and windows 8 phones?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I need to install SQLite plugin for my application. My application is tend to run on both Windows 7 and Windows 8. I tried many plugins which will supports only Windows 8 but not Windows 7 phones. Is there any SQLite plugin which will supports both Windows 7 and 8 phones? Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can provide you some links to some of the plugins that are available out there:

https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-iOS-2013.03

https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin [Only for Windows phone 8+)

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin (again for WP8)

https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-websqldatabase [Cordova plugin enabling WebSqlDatabase on WP7.5 & WP8] \

And here is one more: http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/

A fork of the above plugin: https://github.com/Smile-SA/Csharp-SQLite-WP

Hope this helped.